# How do I create a local workspace in vscode.blockscan.com?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, ethereum, solidity, etherscan

I'm trying to debug and run a code that was deployed on Etherscan via the Terminal.

[image]

I tried downloading the code to my computer and then loading it to vscode.blockscan.com but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

[Etherscan's VSCode](https://vscode.blockscan.com/) viewer is generally for [browsing code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/vscode-web#_relationship-to-vs-code-desktop) in a familiar, editor-like environment.

To edit and test Solidity code using terminal, you should download the source code into your local VSCode editor and make changes or begin testing with tools such as Hardhat/Foundry locally.

ps. you have to export the files one by one for now, a download all button coming soon

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of running programs in VSCode locally and I'm already doing that. But as you can see, there is an option to use the Terminal on the website (in case I don't want to download anything). My question was about how to access that in particular. I see no option to create a local workspace that would access this Terminal (as it states in the image above).

Comment: Terminal is unfortunately not accessible from VSCode web as terminal runs on your local PC, making it read only for web.

You're right that there is no option to "create a local workspace" to transition to local, you have to do that manually by opening the code on your local VSCode as stated above